# what's the simplest way to split a file, based on a pattern right AFTER the split?

Tags: python, regex

#### This is the format of an Ansible log file

Well, basically a header is **followed**, on the same line, by `************************` (not always the same lenth, txs Ansible), then 0..n lines.  It looks to me like a line ending with all `*` is the most reliable logical separator.

```
2020-03-09 20:22:06,257 p=31553 u=myuser n=ansible | Using /mypath/ansible/vbox/ansible.cfg as config file
2020-03-09 20:22:08,004 p=31553 u=myuser n=ansible | PLAY [all] ***************************************************************************************************
2020-03-09 20:22:08,123 p=31553 u=myuser n=ansible | TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************
2020-03-09 20:22:12,618 p=31553 u=myuser n=ansible | ok: [192.169.1.70]
2020-03-09 20:22:12,687 p=31553 u=myuser n=ansible | TASK [debug inventory_hostname] ******************************************************************************
2020-03-09 20:22:12,722 p=31553 u=myuser n=ansible | ok: [192.169.1.70] => {
    "msg": "inventory_hostname:192.169.1.70:"
}
2020-03-09 20:22:12,796 p=31553 u=myuser n=ansible | TASK [load environment-specific variables] *******************************************************************
2020-03-09 20:22:12,813 p=31553 u=myuser n=ansible | ok: [192.169.1.70] => {"ansible_facts": {}, "ansible_included_var_files": ["/mypath/ansible/vbox/vars.environment.yaml"], "changed": false}
2020-03-09 20:22:12,887 p=31553 u=myuser n=ansible | TASK [read npm version] **************************************************************************************
2020-03-09 20:22:13,667 p=31553 u=myuser n=ansible | ok: [192.169.1.70] => {"changed": false, "cmd": "npm --version", "delta": "0:00:00.300431", "end": "2020-03-10 03:22:13.572664", "rc": 0, "start": "2020-03-10 03:22:13.272233", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "6.8.0", "stdout_lines": ["6.8.0"]}
2020-03-09 20:22:13,738 p=31553 u=myuser n=ansible | TASK [read npm version] **************************************************************************************
2020-03-09 20:22:13,766 p=31553 u=myuser n=ansible | ok: [192.169.1.70] => {"ansible_facts": {"npm_version": "6.8.0"}, "changed": false}
2020-03-09 20:22:13,839 p=31553 u=jluc n=ansible | TASK [find dbdumps] ******************************************************************************************
```

#### What I would like:

- header
- separator `********` - or not, it doesn't really matter
- the lines that follow, but not including the next chunk's header.

The chunks can be some text with newlines in it or lists of strings, the exact format isn't super important, I can pick it up after.

I've indicated this chunking with just a newline below.

```
2020-03-09 20:22:06,257 p=31553 u=myuser n=ansible | Using /mypath/ansible/vbox/ansible.cfg as config file

2020-03-09 20:22:08,004 p=31553 u=myuser n=ansible | PLAY [all] 
***************************************************************************************************

2020-03-09 20:22:08,123 p=31553 u=myuser n=ansible | TASK [Gathering Facts] 
***************************************************************************************
2020-03-09 20:22:12,618 p=31553 u=myuser n=ansible | ok: [192.169.1.70]


2020-03-09 20:22:12,687 p=31553 u=myuser n=ansible | TASK [debug inventory_hostname] 
******************************************************************************
2020-03-09 20:22:12,722 p=31553 u=myuser n=ansible | ok: [192.169.1.70] => {
    "msg": "inventory_hostname:192.169.1.70:"
}

2020-03-09 20:22:12,796 p=31553 u=myuser n=ansible | TASK [load environment-specific variables] 
*******************************************************************
2020-03-09 20:22:12,813 p=31553 u=myuser n=ansible | ok: [192.169.1.70] => {"ansible_facts": {}, "ansible_included_var_files": ["/mypath/ansible/vbox/vars.environment.yaml"], "changed": false}

2020-03-09 20:22:12,887 p=31553 u=myuser n=ansible | TASK [read npm version]
**************************************************************************************
... more stuff under read npm...
```

#### I have tried:

```
lines = data.splitlines()
more_itertools.split_at(lines, lambda line: "*****************" in line)
```

```
import re
patre = re.compile(r"(%s)" % (r"\*" * 20))
chunks = patre.split(data)
```

I suppose I can write a state-machine and, when I see `******` on line n, purge everything from n-2 to the previous chunk, then start a chunk with n-1 (the title *above* the current line), then add the current line.

but this seems really complicated and I think I am missing something.  Maybe multiline regex, with pattern match for an arbitrary header line and the `********`?

Sorry about the formatting, for some reason, copying in the raw logfile, even as a code chunk, often doesn't take the linefeeds right before the `*****`, I had to add extra ones manually.

Answer (score 0):

How about to `re.split` on the `********` instances like you did, and then add the lines that follow until the last one (which is the next header). Then add the header with newline separation, and the stars.

```
import re

with open('data.txt') as file:
    data = re.split('\*+', file.read())

s = ''
for x in data:
    lines = x.split('\n')
    for i in range(len(lines) - 1):
        s += lines[i] + '\n'
    s += f'\n\n{lines[-1]}\n' + '*' * 20

with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying that this is the simplest way:

```
def parse_entries(data):
    lines = data.splitlines()
    result = []
    is_header = False
    header = []
    content = []
    pattern = re.compile(r'(^.*?)\s+\*+\s*$')
    for line in lines:
        match = re.search(pattern, line)
        if match:
            if is_header:
                header.append(match.group(1))
            else:
                result.append({"header": "\n".join(header), "content": "\n".join(content)})
                is_header = True
                header = [match.group(1)]
                content = []
        else:
            is_header = False
            content.append(line)
    return result


for entry in parse_entries(data):
    print(f"Header:\n{entry['header']}\nContent:\n{entry['content']}\n")
```